# Calling Custom QMake Function defined in Parent .pro file

Tags: qt, qmake

I have defined a simple qmake function as the one below:

```
defineReplace(generateBoilerPlate){        
     message("Generating boiler plate code...")
}
```

My project is arranged in the following hierachial manner:

```
ProjectDir
    ProjectName.pro
    ModuleName1SubDir
         ModuleName1.pro
    ModuleName2SubDir
         ModuleName2.pro
```

I have defined the aforementioned custom function in ProjectName.pro

I am able to successfully call this function within ProjectName.pro using:

```
out = $$generateBoilerPlate()
```

However, I want to be able to call the custom function 'generateBoilerPlate' from within the .pro files inside the module subdirectories (i.e. in the example above, I want to call the function in ModuleName1.pro AND ModuleName2.pro).

When I try and invoke the function in the submodules' .pro files, I get the following error:

```
 'generateBoilerPlate' is not a recognized replace function.
```

Can someone please tell me how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As possible solution, you can define your functions in separate `.pri` file and [include](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html#include-filename) it in your `.pro` files whenever you need your to use your functions.